# Graph's tooltip is not coming properly in plotly

Tags: plotly

I created plottly graph referring this tutorial https://plot.ly/javascript/filled-area-plots/ .But tool tip is not coming properly for left and right side.Some part of tooltip is hiding. It should not be.

Is there any possibility to display both tool tip in right side when mouse over on left side of graph and vice versa?

I am sharing screen shot also.Please guide.

[image]

Here is my code :-

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>  
<div id="myDiv" style="width: 480px; height: 400px;"><!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV --></div>
<script>
var abc = ['2013-10-04 02:23:00', '2013-10-22 12:23:00',  '2013-11-04 20:23:00', '2013-11-020 10:23:00','2013-12-04 15:10:45', '2013-12-26 06:03:00'];
abc[6]='2014-05-02 20:23:00';
var trace1 = {
x: abc,
y: [1, 3, 6,9, 4, 5,8],
  fill: 'tozeroy',
  fillcolor: 'red',
  text: server1,
  hoverinfo: "x+y+text",
  type: 'scatter',
  mode:"markers",
  marker:
  {
    size:4,
    color:"gray"
  },
  uid:"c2e171",
  dragmode:"turntable"
};
var layout = {
  margin: {
    l: 35,
    r: 40,
    b: 50,
    t: 10
  },
  legend: {
    "orientation": "h"
  },
  xaxis: {
    showgrid: false,
    showline: true,
    ticks: "outside"
  },
  yaxis : {
    fixedrange: true,
    showgrid: false,
    showline: true,
    ticks: "outside"
  },
  dragmode:false,
};
var data = [trace1];
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data,layout, {modeBarButtonsToRemove: ['sendDataToCloud','hoverCompareCartesian','zoom2d','pan2d','select2d','lasso2d','autoScale2d','hoverClosestCartesian','toggleSpikelines']});

var plotDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');
plotDiv.on('plotly_relayout',
function(eventdata){  
    alert( 'ZOOM!' + '\n\n' +
        'Event data:' + '\n' + 
         JSON.stringify(eventdata) + '\n\n' +
        'x-axis start:' + new Date(eventdata['xaxis.range[0]'])+ '\n' +
        'x-axis end:' + new Date(eventdata['xaxis.range[1]']));
        var xVal = new Date(eventdata['xaxis.range[0]']);
        var yVal = new Date(eventdata['xaxis.range[1]']);
});

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm facing same problem. Any one have solution please provide us.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to increase the z-index of the tooltip. I investigate it with the element overview in chrome developer tools. The following object structure (DOM) builds plotly in a plot to the Tooltip `<div id="myDiv">` -> `<div class="plot-container plotly">` -> `<div class="svg-container">` -> `<svg class="main-svg">` -> `<g class="hoverlayer">`

So just append css on top of your html or something like this:

```
<style>
  #myDiv .hoverlayer:{
    z-index: 100
  }
</style>
```

**Note** that this is in my point of view a dirty solution. But I don't know how to solve it with using just the library api

Comment: No, it's not a proper answer.

Comment: Downvotes without comment isn't good for other readers. Please give explanation why this is not good. Note that I have a hint at the end of my answer that says "Note that is in my point of view a dirty solution". But better to have any direction for a possible solution than : "it is NOT possible"-answer.